# .net core entity framework create tables inside existing database

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core-2.1, entity-framework-core-2.1

I don't want to give my sql user the permissions to create databases.

Is there any way to create the database manually and then have entity framework create the tables inside it?

Comment: have you tried combination of DB first and Code first? So first step would be to pull all from existing db to you code with db first approach, and later whatever you change, like change the field name, or adding new table etc, you need to migrate with code first commands.. I'm not sure this is the best way but I'm pretty sure it would work.. Here is something that might be useful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/existing-database

Comment: I will give it a read, but the link you have provided is for Entity framework 6 not core. (but who knows it might help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm certain EF Core is smart enough to handle this case. Just create the database, set your permissions and run the command `dotnet ef update-database` (assuming you have a valid migration).

Usually, an application (or multiple applications) use the same database from separate `DbContext` classes, which handle their own bounded context (a logical piece of the whole). That would require being able to recognize that Databases and Tables have already been created, and issue appropriate add and alter commands to the schema.